# Supremum of random variable and function

Tags: random-variables, supremum-and-infimum

I have a silly question that, however, I'm not sure of what's the answer.
If I have $$\sup_{0 \le s \le t}\big(X_s-s\big)$$ where $t \ge s$
then it correspond to $\sup_{0 \le s \le t}(X_s)-s$
or to $\sup_{0 \le s \le t}(X_s)-0$??  So the supremum impact also on the deterministic function or not?

Comment: Neither of those two is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we have that the following inequality holds:
$$\sup_{0 \le s \le t}\big(X_s-Y_s\big)\leq \sup_{0 \le s \le t}X_s +\sup_{0 \le s \le t}(-Y_s)=\sup_{0 \le s \le t}X_s -\inf_{0 \le s \le t}Y_s.$$
Moreover both $\sup_{0 \le s \le t}X_s$ and $\inf_{0 \le s \le t}Y_s$ depend on $t$ (not on $s$). For $Y_s=s$, $\inf_{0 \le s \le t}Y_s=0$.

Comment: okey, so $sup_{0 \le s \le t}(X_s)$ is a function of t, right? and what if I have $sup_{s \ge 0}(X_s)$?

Comment: @Alias__ $\sup_{s \ge 0}(X_s)$  is a real constant or $+\infty$ if $X_s$ is not bounded.